# Hibernate criteria to fetch the records?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have below records in table.

```
    col1  col2  col3
------------------------
    1     Abc    IN
    2     DEF    CA
    3     Xyz    IN
    4     Cae    CA
    5     Pty    IN
    6     Zwe    DE
    7     Zwf    US
```

Here User sends an Input like **IN** or **CA** or **DE** etc. User input has to be mapped against **col3**. Now I need to query **all the records** from the table but the records matching the user input (**IN** or **CA** or **DE**) should appear first in the list then all other records should appear. How can I do it using hibernate criteria?

I need the results in below the order if user sends **IN** as an input.

```
    1     Abc    IN
    5     Pty    IN
    3     Xyz    IN
    2     DEF    CA
    4     Cae    CA
    6     Zwe    DE
    7     Zwf    US
```

Comment: is creating two queries or sorting on Java side an option (Hibernate doesn't support UNION ALL out of the box)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot do two queries because I have the pagination concept and I have to take only 3 rows each time applying above logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use ORDER BY CASE construct:

`order by case when <your entity>.col3 = :parameter then '0' else '1' end asc`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using criteria not hql . Is it possible using criteria?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.Case.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem:
1. Create two queries one with equal to another with not equal to and all results for both in single list.
2. If you don't want to query database twice then you have to write algo in java that will remove elements for your input from list and add it another list and after iteration add remaining list at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot do two queries because I have the pagination concept and I have to take only 3 rows each time applying above logic.

Answer (score 0):

try the `case ... when` statements:

```
select *, ( case when col3=:input then '0' | col3 else col3 end) as sorter from table order by sorter asc
```

not sure, if it works, but if it does it would be exactly what you want